# Operator + overloading in base class and using it in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have 2 classes, base (with copy constructor) and derived, in base Ι have overloaded `operator+`:

```
class Base {

  public:

     Base(const Base& x) {
         // some code for copying
     }

     Base operator+(const Base &bignum) const {
         Base x;
         /* ... */
         return x;
     }
};

class Derived : public Base {
};
```

And when i try to do something like that

```
Derived x;
Derived y;
Derived c=x+y;
```

I get error: `conversion from "Base" to non-scalar type "Derived" derived`
Could problem be in that operator + returns object of `Base` type and I want assign it to `Derived` type object?

Comment: Yes, exactly it's the assignment and only the assigment.  All you need is a constructor, to explain the compiler how to put a Base into a Derived without harm.

Answer (score 10):

In fact you don't need to redefine the `operator+` (unless your design requires it, as Ajay's example pointed out).

### It works better than you think

Take the following minimalistic example:

```
struct Base {
    Base operator+ (Base a) const
        { cout <<"Base+Base\n"; }
    Base& operator= (Base a)  
        { cout<<"Base=Base\n"; }
};
struct Derived : public Base { };

int main() {
    Base a,b,c;  
    c=a+b;     // prints out "Base+Base" and "Base=Base"
    Derived e,f,g; 
    e+f;       // prints out "Base+Base" (implicit conversion); 
}
```

This works perfectly, because when encountering `e+f` the compiler finds `operator+` of the base class, and he implicitly convert from `Derived` to `Base`, and computes a result which is of type `Base`.  You could easily write `c=e+f`.

### What's missing ?

The problem starts only with the **assigment to a Derived**.  As soon as you try `g=e+f;` you will get an error.  The compiler doesn't know for sure how to put an A into a B. This prudence is justified by common wisdom: *All apes are annimals, but all animals are not necessarily apes*.

And this is even more obvious if `Derived` has more fields than `Base` : how should the compilier initialise them ?  Basically, how to tell the compiler how he shall make a `Derived` out of something else ?   With a constructor !

```
struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived()=default; 
    Derived(const Base& a) : Base(a) { cout<<"construct B from A\n"; }
};
```

Once you have defined this, everything works as you'd expect:

```
 g=e+f;   // will automatically construct a Derived from the result
          // and then execute `Derived`'s default `operator=` which 
          // will call `Base`'s `operator=`
```

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/ieOG22).

Comment: Thank you! Was stuck on this problem for awhile, this was clearly explained and your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a correct design. Consider a class `Point2D` having `x` and `y`, and `Point3D` class which is inheriting from `Point2D` having additional member `z`. Do you thing following will help?

```
Point2D operator+(const Point2D &pt) const;
```

When called as:

```
Point3D a, b;
Point3D c = a+b;
```

?

Comment: Yes, I know, but in that case my Derived class gives me only few more methods, no new variables, so what's the problem using this that way? Sorry for no mention about this.

Comment: But that won't pacify the compiler. Virtual functions may be hindrance, if there are any. You may write a `BaseToDerived` function, privately in base class. Write all such functions in `Derived`,  which would call base' version (and get `Base`). Then call this (private) function to return `Derived`.

Comment: I don't understand for what reason should I do it like that?

Comment: For example, for implementing the `operator+` in `Derived` class, so that any user of `Derived` can call it without facing warning. And to re-use the base' implementation of the same.

Comment: Like I said the only methods in Derived class are overloaded operator/ and operator* . If I did operator+ what sense would be to have 2 classes. I know it's weird problem, but that's problem from university.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly the problem. The plus operator is only guaranteed to return a Base object, so you can assign it to a Base object. All Derived objects can be substituted for Bases, but not the other way.

Comment: ok, so is it good way to solve this by creating copy constructor in `Derived` class which takes `Base` type object, and do something like that:
`Derived(const Base& x) :Base(x) {}` ??

Comment: That would work, but it hints at potential bigger problems with how your code is designed (potential misuse of inheritance). It's strange that Base objects have all of the information in them needed to become Dervied objects.

Comment: It's only academic problem, we have to do derived class which have only few more methods, no new variables.

Comment: What's the statement of the problem?

Comment: I have class which keeps big numbers in bcd. In this base class I have overloaded `operator+` and `operator-`. Now I have to create derived class to this Bignum class, where will be overloaded `operator*` and `operator/`

Comment: The cleanest thing to do here is probably add a Dervied operator+(const Derived &) that does the right thing internally

Comment: I can't do it. Operator+ can only be in base class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77378/discussion-between-alfred-rossi-and-bingo157).