# c++ inheritance: 2 times overloaded operator+ in base class are not working proper in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, overloading

I wrote my generic class "MyVector" based on std::valarray

```
//myvector.h
#ifndef MYVECTOR_H
#define MYVECTOR_H
#include <valarray>

template <typename T> 
class MyVector
{
public:
 MyVector(int size){larr.resize(size);}
 MyVector<T>& operator=(const MyVector<T>& other) 
    {
    this->larr=other.larr;
    return *this;
    }
 MyVector<T> operator+ ( const MyVector<T>& rhs);   //body in .cpp file
 template <typename U> 
 MyVector<T> operator+ (const U& val);              //body in .cpp file
protected:
std::valarray larr;
}
#endif
```

```
//myvector.cpp

/*****other code*****/

template <typename T>
MyVector<T> MyVector<T>::operator+ ( const MyVector<T>& rhs)
{
    MyVector<T> lv; lv.larr = this->larr + rhs.larr;
    return  lv;  
}

template <typename T>
template <typename U> 
MyVector<T> MyVector<T>::operator+ (const U& val)
{
    MyVector<T> lv; lv.larr = this->larr + static_cast<T> (val);
    return  lv;  
}

/*****other code*****/
```

Then I try to write a derived class DataVector, with all the functions of MyVector, especially, all my overloaded operators.

```
#ifndef DATAVECTOR_H
#define DATAVECTOR_H
#include "myvector.h"

class dataVector : public MyVector<int>
{
public:
    dataVector& operator=(const dataVector& other) 
    {
        this->larr=other.larr;
        return *this;
    }
    using MyVector<int>::operator=;
    using MyVector<int>::operator+;
}
#endif
```

When I try to compile main.cpp,

```
//main.cpp
#include "datavector.h"
#include "myvector.h"

dataVector datav1(10);
dataVector datav2(10);
dataVector datav3(10);

//if i write:
datav1=datav1 + 10;  //works (gmake and compiler gcc7.5 on ubuntu)
//if i write:
datav3=datav1 + datav2;  //does not work (gmake and compiler gcc7.5 on ubuntu)
```

I obtain this compiler error:

```
myvector.cpp: In instantiation of ‘MyVector<T> MyVector<T>::operator+(const U&) [with U = dataVector; T = int]’:
myvector.cpp:xxx:yy: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const dataVector’ to type ‘int’
     MyVector<T> lv; lv.larr = this->larr + static_cast<T> (val);
```

If I use MyVector: MyVector3=MyVector1+MyVector2 works well.

Can anyone help me? 
I know this code isn't well writed, but I'm still learning.
thank you.

Comment: There is an answer already at <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138023/operator-overloading-in-base-class-and-using-it-in-derived-class>.

Comment: @stackoverblown No, that question doesn't actually overload `operator+` in the base, and it's not templated either, both of which are relevant to this example.

Comment: template code in cpp is suspicious

Comment: Do you really want `template <typename U> 
 MyVector<T> operator+ (const U& val);` (which matches `dataVector`) and not simply `MyVector<T> operator+ (const T& val);`?

Comment: thank you all, @Jarod42 I'll try to adjust my .cpp code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while when you add `MyVector` to `MyVector`, `MyVector::operator+ ( const MyVector<T>& rhs)` matches, but when you add `dataVector` to `dataVector`, `dataVector::operator+ (const U& val)` (inherited from `MyVector`) becomes a better match as it accepts *anything*, not necessarily something covertible to `T`. There are several possible solutions.

1. Make `dataVector` a typedef, like `using dataVector = MyVector<int>`, if suitable.
2. Add an `operator+` accepting `dataVector`; it may call the inherited operator using an explicit cast (like `*this + (const MyVector<int> &)rhs`).
3. Restrict the `MyVector::operator+ (const U& val)` to accept `T` only, as suggested by Jarod42.
4. (The hard way) Restrict the `MyVector::operator+ (const U& val)` to accept sane types only using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (like `template <typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type>`, or maybe `is_convertible_to`, or whatever appropriate).

Comment: thank you, and thanks to @jarod42, I added typename U for my convenience, . I didn't want re-write operator, because I overloaded +,-,*,/,==. I'll try the third solution, thanks for your help.